# Разбиение строки python с последующим заносом элементов в список Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как из этого

```
coord = ['0GPGGA,070829.00,4947.9147,N,03643.2108,E,1,06,1.6,1307.6,M,16.1,M,*50']
```

Сделать это

```
new_coord = [['0GPGGA'], ['070829.00'], ['4947.9147']...]
```

Comment: [`str.split(',')`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html)  вам в помощь

Answer (score 2):

```
coord = ['0GPGGA,070829.00,4947.9147,N,03643.2108,E,1,06,1.6,1307.6,M,16.1,M,*50']
result = [[x] for x in coord[0].split(',')]
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь давать чуть более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: а зачем регулярки, если строки и сами не плохо справляются? `[[x] for x in coord[0].split(',')]`

Comment: @bopoh да, поторопился( , привел к более оптимальному решению

Comment: @alexanderbarakin что значит более развернутый ответ, если там по сути решение в одну строку, требуется описать последовательность действий ?

Comment: нет, конечно, не «требуется», но объяснение решения всегда приветствуется. к слову, после правки ваш ответ полностью идентичен соседнему. возможно, лучше было не заменять написанное, а привести все варианты, пояснив (к примеру), какой из них лучше и чем именно.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin я отредактировал ответ потому как это не запрещено и я хочу обратить внимание что ни каким образом не опирался на соседний ответ, просто увидел комментарий Ворона

Answer (score 0):

```
coord = ['0GPGGA,070829.00,4947.9147,N,03643.2108,E,1,06,1.6,1307.6,M,16.1,M,*50']
new_coord = [[x] for x in coord[0].split(',')]
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь давать чуть более развёрнутые ответы.

Answer (score -1):

```
raw = [x.split(",") for x in open("data.txt")]

data = open("final_data.txt", 'w')

counter = 0

for a in raw:

    del raw[counter][0]

    del raw[counter][5:8]

    del raw[counter][6:10]

    counter += 1
```

Как-то так, в цикле удаляю ненужные поля